# Remove double entry from orignial table when joining

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I've got 2 tables:
adresses and a log of files (named send) i've sent.

For a given file, I want to get all adresses, and whether they received the file or not.

What I've got so far is this:

```
SELECT            *
,                 CASE 
                      WHEN send.fileid = 1 THEN 1 
                      ELSE send.fileid = NULL 
                  END as file1 
FROM              send
RIGHT OUTER JOIN `adress` 
              ON `send`.adressid = `adress`.`id`
```

The problem is, when an adress got two diffrent files, they get listed twice. How can I alter the statement to get arround this?

Example Data

```
*adress*
1 Adrian
2 Christian
3 Max
4 Alex

*file*
1 music
2 video
3 document

*send*
adress:1 file:1
adress:1 file:2 -
adress:3 file:1
adress:4 file:2 -
adress:4 file:3

when i browse the file 2, i want to see:
X Adrian
X Alex
Christian
Max
```

TLDR: I want all my adresses (once) with either the specific file id or null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, switch to LEFT JOIN. Most people find left join hard enough to get, and get way more confused by right join.

Comment: If an address has two different files, you'll have to decide which of those you want to select. Can you add some sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM adress
LEFT JOIN send ON send.adressid = adress.id
AND send.fileid =1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

that seems to be it

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about is is putting the condition in a subquery and letting the outer join do all the heavy lifting:

```
SELECT    a.*, s.fieldid
FROM      address a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT filedid, addressid
           FROM   send
           WHERE  fileid = 1) ON s.addressid = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can do this just by using GROUP BY?

I put together a quick example, then realised this is MySQL.  I think the fundamental approach is the same, but the example won't work., as this is SQL Server syntax:

```
DECLARE @address TABLE (address_id INT, address_name VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @address SELECT 1, 'Adrian';
INSERT INTO @address SELECT 2, 'Christian';
INSERT INTO @address SELECT 3, 'Max';
INSERT INTO @address SELECT 4, 'Alex';
DECLARE @file TABLE ([file_id] INT, [file_name] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @file SELECT 1, 'music';
INSERT INTO @file SELECT 2, 'video';
INSERT INTO @file SELECT 3, 'document';
DECLARE @send TABLE (address_id INT, [file_id] INT);
INSERT INTO @send SELECT 1, 1;
INSERT INTO @send SELECT 1, 2;
INSERT INTO @send SELECT 3, 1;
INSERT INTO @send SELECT 4, 2;
INSERT INTO @send SELECT 4, 3;

SELECT
    a.address_id,
    a.address_name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.[File_id] = 1 THEN 'X' END) AS file_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.[File_id] = 2 THEN 'X' END) AS file_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN f.[File_id] = 3 THEN 'X' END) AS file_3
FROM
    @address a
    LEFT JOIN @send s ON s.address_id = a.address_id
    LEFt JOIN @file f ON f.[file_id] = s.[file_id]
GROUP BY
    a.address_id,
    a.address_name
ORDER BY
    a.address_id;
```

This gives a matrix of address and files, i.e.:

```
address_id  address_name    file_1  file_2  file_3
1           Adrian          X       X       NULL
2           Christian       NULL    NULL    NULL
3           Max             X       NULL    NULL
4           Alex            NULL    X       X
```